# MongoDB set field based on another fields

Tags: mongodb

Say this is a document of mine:

```
{
    'negative': 32,
    'positive': 68
}
```

I have nearly 600k documents like this. What I want to do is add a `sentiment` field based on the largest key amont negative and positive fields. In this example, sentiment should be "positive".

I can do it by updating all documents using python but it would took a lot of time. Can it achieved with aggregation so I won't have to change the data itself?

Comment: Check this out: [updates with aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/)

Comment: Thank you. I'm on it.